# Как запустить виджет в  Android-эмуляторе?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Вот сделал я Android виджет. Хочу добавить его на хоумскрин, но при добавлении не вижу. При запуске в эклипсе вот что пишет:

[image]

Что делать? Как быть?

Comment: Раз его не нельзя добавить, значит скорее всего он установлен на sd карту. А просто так взять и запустить виджет - нельзя.

Comment: в эмуляторе нет sd карты у меня. причем, в списке запущенных приложений виджет есть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй длинный тычок на пустое место, куда добавил виджет. Если появится контекстное меню или таскалка - значит, виджет добавился, но невидимый (с прозрачной картинкой) - т.е. ты что-то напутал с ресурсом, который у тебя на виджете должен отображаться.

Еще была пара случаев, когда это случалось совсем спонтанно, помогал клин-редеплой. Возможно, sdk глюкнуло и забыло упаковать картинку в apk.

```
// FIXME В след. раз лучше делай скриншот вкладки LogCat, в логе консоли видно только установку приложения
```